# Blazor Form - User Input Sanitization (<InputText>, <InputTextArea> etc)

Tags: asp.net-core, xss, blazor, sanitization, cross-site

I am working on Blazor application where I have a form which take user input (form with some text boxes & text area). What is best approach to prevent it from cross site scripting and `XSS` attacks.

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` for other components for encoding and decoding html. Will encoding & decoding on user input suffice and prevent attacks, vulnerabilities etc.

Do I have to use some library such as `Gans.XSS.HtmlSanitizer` or is there some inbuilt feature in Blazor.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since the inputs should be binding to a model inside an `<EditForm>` component, and that model is a class, can you use the inbuilt `<DataAnnotationsValidator />` to get this done using a regular expression? you could build out your Model class with a Regex data annotation on the related properties:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class ModelToBindTo()
{
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9 _.-]*")] //Check/tweak this before use, going from memory 
    public string PropertyToBindInputText { get; set;}
}
```

By binding to this and using the validator this **should** restrict any input characters that could get you into trouble, and you could run it against a regex again on the server side if needed to double check before persisting the data or doing anything else with it.

[Further details on validator can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
[Data Annotations reference can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Do not use Regular Expressions (Regex) to validate HTML according to the best practices. I would suggest the following library https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer which is an active library and updated regularly.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to use some library such as Gans.XSS.HtmlSanitizer or is there some inbuilt feature in Blazor.

The Blazor does not have a built-in feature to sanitizes the inputs, such as `InputText`. So I create a custom `DbCommandInterceptor` and sanitizes the all input before I save them into the database such as follow:

```
public class CorrectCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{

    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(

        DbCommand command,
        CommandEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        ApplyCorrectCommand(command);
        return result;
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(
        DbCommand command,
        CommandEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        ApplyCorrectCommand(command);
        return ValueTask.FromResult(result);
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<int> NonQueryExecuting(
        DbCommand command,
        CommandEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<int> result)
    {
        ApplyCorrectCommand(command);
        return result;
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> NonQueryExecutingAsync(
        DbCommand command,
        CommandEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<int> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        ApplyCorrectCommand(command);
        return ValueTask.FromResult(result);
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<object> ScalarExecuting(
        DbCommand command,
        CommandEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<object> result)
    {
        ApplyCorrectCommand(command);
        return result;
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<object>> ScalarExecutingAsync(
        DbCommand command,
        CommandEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<object> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        ApplyCorrectCommand(command);
        return ValueTask.FromResult(result);
    }

    private static void ApplyCorrectCommand(DbCommand command)
    {
        command.CommandText = command.CommandText.ApplyCorrect();

        foreach (DbParameter parameter in command.Parameters)
        {
            switch (parameter.DbType)
            {
                case DbType.AnsiString:
                case DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength:
                case DbType.String:
                case DbType.StringFixedLength:
                case DbType.Xml:
                    if (!(parameter.Value is DBNull) && parameter.Value is string)
                    {
                        parameter.Value = Convert.ToString(parameter.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ApplyCorrect();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in `ApplyCorrect` method I call the [HtmlSanitizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlSanitizer/#versions-body-tab) as follow:

```
public static string ApplyCorrect(this string input)
    {
        string sanitizedInput = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
            sanitizedInput = sanitizer.Sanitize(input);
        }
        return sanitizedInput;
    }
```

I recommend that do not use Regular Expressions (Regex) to validate HTML according to the best practices. I would suggest the following library [mganss/HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) which is an active library and updated regularly which you also mentioned in your question.